# How to determine effectiveness of clustering key in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have cluster GA data to query it more effectively.
For now, that cluster date is stored as Numeric and it is converted to date in a view

How do I determine (from the explain plan) whether filtering on that column is **effective in pruning the cluster key**, after executing a query like this:

```
Select <A few columns> 
FROM GA_SESSION_VIEW WHERE
(​TO_DATE​(​TO_CHAR​(​GA_SESSION_VIEW​.​DATE​)​, 'YYYYMMDD'​)​​)​ >=
current_date-1
```

I see in the explain plan that not all partitions are pruned. But I am also not selecting all columns. I am not able to see what the cause of this is, ie: not selecting all columns or the filter on the clustering key.

Comment: a partition holds all the columns for that partition, but if you are only load half the columns from the table, you will only transfer half the data of the partition. So partitions read verse total is 100% pruning. To see the difference in columns selected makes, do a select * and see how the data transferred goes up, but for the same filters, the number of partitions stays the same.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that @SimeonPilgrim, this should help me... But still it would be nice if the SF explain plan made it explicit that a clustering key has been used 'effectively'

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the average depth of the table for a specified column (an indicator of better clustering) use https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/system_clustering_depth.html  So in your case

```
select SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_DEPTH( 'GA_SESSION_VIEW' , '(DATE)');
```

Comment: This still does not tell me whether a clustered table column, wrapped with conversion logic actually is used properly.

Comment: So is your question actually something like "Is Snowflake's partition pruning strategy effective when a predicate includes a function?"  In that case, the answer is yes, in my experience.

Couldn't you test this by hardcoding the result of your function and seeing if the "Partitions Scanned" is the same?

Comment: Oh damn, you are totally right Nat. Feel kind of stupid now...

Comment: That's not stupid--I haven't done the test myself so I am interested in the results too.  Please post as an answer when you find out!